# Find the range of $ln(x+y-4)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The domain is:

$x+y\gt4$

The range of course is all the values that result from the inputs within the domain. However I have no idea how I can get an interval since I'm used to an interval representing all the allowable inputs for one variable not two.

Comment: Every possible input will be passed to logarithm, so range will be all real numbers

Comment: First find all possible values that $x+y-4$ can take if $x+y >4$.

Comment: but that is rather difficult that occured to me i have to think of so many pairs.

Comment: I tried all real numbers but that is also not true you can"t take ln of a negative input so not all inputs will be passed

Comment: since the range is the inverse which is e it can take on all real numbers. I had to do some reading

Comment: " I'm used to an interval representing all the allowable inputs for one variable not two."  Then say $w = x+y-4$  have any idea what the range of $w$ is?  If you are having a tough time with "so many pairs," can you think of an upper bound, and  a lower bound?  Is $w$ continuous?  What he the range $\ln w$ over that interval?